# Problema ao inserir objeto com ManyToOne JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Vou tentar exemplificar meu problema com classes mais simples do que na minha aplicação:

Tenho por exemplo a classe Principal e uma classe Item. Em Principal, tenho uma propriedade do tipo Item anotada com ManyToOne, que mapeio no banco apenas pelo id_item na minha tabela Principal.

Ao criar uma instância da classe principal na interface web da minha aplicação, eu seleciono uma instância de Item em um "select" que tem apenas o id e o nome do Item (Imagine que item tem várias outras propriedades que não enviei para o client da aplicação). Ao selecionar um Item para associar à Principal, Atribuo uma nova instância de Item ao Principal e seto o Id deste item corretamente nessa instancia.
envio então Principal para o lado server da aplicação e persisto usando JPA com o Insert.

Porém, ao recuperar a lista de Principais do banco, meu novo item não tem a descrição de Item nem as demais propriedades que deveria ter. Foi gravado tudo corretamente no banco, uma vez que se eu fizer um select, está lá, na minha linha 1 da tabela principal tem o id_item = 3 por exemplo referente ao item 3 corretamente cadastrado na tabela Item. Mas o JPA não traz os demais dados de Item.
É como se ele tivesse criado uma nova instância em cache do Item 3 contendo apenas o id e usa esta na listagem dos Principais.

Aí, tentei resolver este problema adicionando cascade=CascadeType.ALL na anotação ManyToOne do Item na classe Principal. Porém, ao fazer isso, tenho uma mensagem de erro ao tentar salvar o Principal contendo o Item apenas com o Id, dizendo que o Item está desatachado. (java.sql.SQLException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:pacote.Item)

Eu consigo imaginar 2 soluções para o problema:
1) Passar o objeto Item inteiro para o client da aplicação e devolvê-lo inteiro associado ao Principal no momento de Salvar o Principal.
2) Buscar no banco o objeto Item pelo id da instancia de Item que veio do client e associar esta instância do banco ao Principal antes de persistir o novo Principal ao banco.

Imagino que ambas devam funcionar, embora não tenha testado, mas a primeira solução, gera trafego adicional na rede, e a segunda, acessos extras ao banco.

Existe alguma terceira opção?

Se minha explicação não ficou clara o bastante com a explicação com as classes fictícias, a minha aplicação está no github em github.com/codigoalvo/lab-rest e as classes em questão são Transação como Principal e Categoria e Conta como Item.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que nem é possível a primeira opção, seria muita gabiarra, só se o objeto estiver na sessão. Mas eu faria com a segunda opção. Você pega o que o usuário selecionou no campo do *select*, busca no banco de dados o objeto referente ao que ele selecionou e atribiu à instância de Principal.